# How to set variables once in a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables

Im currently working with a small project where I have done a proxy converter format as well as availability of proxies that are being in use.

Currently I have ended up doing something like this:

```
import random
import threading
import time
from typing import Dict

from loguru import logger


class ProxyManager(object):
    def __init__(self, proxy_file_path=None):
        self.proxies = self.load_proxies(proxy_file_path) if proxy_file_path else {}

    @staticmethod
    def load_proxies(proxy_file_path):
        with open(proxy_file_path) as proxy_file:
            proxies = {'https': [], 'http': []}
            for proxy in proxy_file.readlines():
                if proxy.count(':') > 1:
                    ip, port, username, password = proxy.rstrip().split(':')
                    url = f'http://{ip}:{port}:{username}@{password}'
                else:
                    ip, port = proxy.rstrip().split(':')
                    url = f'http://{ip}:{port}'
                proxies['https'].append(url)

            return proxies

    def random_proxy_https(self):
        return random.choice(self.proxies['https'])

    def all_proxies_https(self):
        return [proxy for proxy in self.proxies['https']]


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proxies path
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
proxies: Dict[str, ProxyManager] = {
    "rotating": ProxyManager("./proxies/rotating.txt"),
    "test": ProxyManager("./proxies/test.txt")
}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proxies available
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
all_proxies = proxies["rotating"].all_proxies_https()
proxy_dict = dict(zip(all_proxies, ['available'] * len(all_proxies)))

proxy_lock: threading = threading.Lock()


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Initialize availability of proxies
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
class AvailableProxies:
    def __enter__(self):
        proxy_lock.acquire()
        self.proxy = None

        while not self.proxy:
            available = [
                att for att, value in proxy_dict.items() if "available" in value
            ]
            if available:
                self.proxy = random.choice(available)
                proxy_dict[self.proxy] = "busy"
                break
            else:
                logger.info("Waiting ... no proxies available")
                time.sleep(.2)

        proxy_lock.release()
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        proxy_dict[self.proxy] = "available"
```

The idea is that I will have mulitple scripts that will be needing the ProxyManager class but not the `AvailableProxies` - That means that I do not need to set the variables

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proxies available
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
all_proxies = proxies["rotating"].all_proxies_https()
proxy_dict = dict(zip(all_proxies, ['available'] * len(all_proxies)))

proxy_lock: threading = threading.Lock()
```

if specific script does not require the class. I wonder if its possible to set the variables inside the class `AvailableProxies` and that the variables `all_proxies, proxy_dict & proxy_lock` should be only set once inside the class when we import the `AvailableProxies` into a script?

Comment: even if the class isnt imported it will still be instantiated as a class - thats how importing works in python - so how do you plan on it not running when it's inside the class ? an `if` statement of some kind?

Comment: Hi @AntiMatterDynamite My thought was that in other scripts, I could do for example: `from proxies import ProxyManager, AvailableProxies` and my thought was that if I e.g. just do `from proxies import ProxyManager` without `AvailableProxies` then there is no need to to set the variables for `all_proxies, proxy_dict & proxy_lock`, if that make sense?

Comment: there's no way to detect which class is being imported this way, at least not one that i know of in python 3.9 - the module will still be imported fully it just wont clutter your global namespace if you use the `from x import y` style imports

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite ahh I see! Then in that case I would keep it as it is and can only thank you for ur answer :D